# Running a Regression and Unclear How to Think About the Problem

Tags: regression, mathematical-statistics, linear, engineering-statistics

I am wanting to run a linear regression to better understand how force is a function of position in terms of delaminating/warping face frames. This is with respect to a product manufactured related to mechanical engineering. So I took force measurements at 8 different locations around the face frame for 20 separate units. I am using the unit location number as the x value (independent variable) and the force measured as the y value (dependent variable).

I am unsure how to set up a regression in excel because I have 20 individual entries for each position on the face frame. But I want to be able to see the data and perhaps predict how high the force will be based on 6 out of the 8 locations (which showed higher force values in my testing). How would I set this up? I will attach a couple of pictures to provide some background.
In this first image, the measurements from left to right are min, avg, max, std deviation, and range (following by the individual measurements for each of the 20 frames). The second picture show a range graph where I have pinpointed the range of force measurements based on the location (x-axis).
[image]

[image]